# Expression Trees with subquery

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

My objective is to create a subquery expression tree for a dynamic Full Text Search. In SQL it would be the equivalent of

```
SELECT * 
FROM MV 
WHERE MV.ID IN (SELECT ID  
                FROM MVF 
                WHERE title = "foo" OR Description = "foo")
```

So the basic idea is to create the FTS subquery, get the ids from that and use those for the In predicate. My issue is with the second part of that.

```
// Get subquery for FTS tables
ParameterExpression ftsParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MVF), "mvfts");
var wphrase = Expression.Constant("foo");
var methodInfo = typeof(string).GetMethod("Equals", new Type[] { typeof(string) });

var ftsID = Expression.Property(ftsParam, "ID");
var ftsTitle = Expression.Property(ftsParam, "Title");
var ftsDescrip = Expression.Property(ftsParam, "Description");

var texp = Expression.Call(ftsTitle, methodInfo, wphrase);
var dexp = Expression.Call(ftsDescrip, methodInfo, wphrase);
var ftsExp = Expression.Or(texp, dexp);


// Now get ids from the above fts resultset
// THE ASSIGNMENT BELOW THROWS
var selectExp = Expression.Call(typeof(IEnumerable<MVF>), "Select", new Type[]
        {
           typeof(long)
        },
        ftsExp,
        Expression.Lambda<Func<MFV, long>>(
            ftsID,
            ftsParam
        )
);

// Now set up MV table reference
ParameterExpression vParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MV), "mv");
var mvID = Expression.Property(vParam, "MVID");
var containsInfo = typeof(IEnumerable<long>).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(long) });

// Now combine expression to get those mvs with ids in the result set of fts query
var containsExp = Expression.Call(selectExp, containsInfo, mvID);
return Expression.Lambda<Func<MV, bool>>(containsExp, vParam);
```

Exception is:

> No generic method 'Select' on type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MVF]' is compatible with the
>   supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be
>   provided if the method is non-generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both methods needed by the expression in question are static generic extension methods (with the most important being *static* and *generic*) of the `Enumerable` class:

[`Enumerable.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TResult> selector
)
```

[`Enumerable.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public static bool Contains<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    TSource value
)
```

The most convenient way of "calling" such methods is the following [`Expression.Call`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351107(v=vs.110).aspx) method overload:

```
public static MethodCallExpression Call(
    Type type,
    string methodName,
    Type[] typeArguments,
    params Expression[] arguments
)
```

The `Type type` argument is the type of the class defining the method being called (`typeof(Enumerable)` in this case) and the `Type[] typeArguments` is the array with the types of the generic type arguments (empty for non generic methods, should be `{ typeof(TSource), typeof(TResult) }` for `Select` and `{ typeof(TSource) }` for `Contains`).

Applying it to your scenario:

```
var selectExp = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable), 
    "Select",
    new { typeof(MFV), typeof(long) },
    ftsExp,
    Expression.Lambda<Func<MFV, long>>(ftsID, ftsParam)
);
```

and

```
var containsExp = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable),
    "Contains",
    new [] { typeof(long) },
    selectExp,
    mvID
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`typeof(IEnumerable<long>)` does not define a select method. The Linq Select Methods are Extension Methods not visible directly via reflection. The class that defines them is `Enumerable`. However `typeof(Enumerable)` will not work either as the method is generic. You have to get the generic method from the class enumerable first and then use [`MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a method which takes a long parameter.

```
var method = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "Select" &&
                                    m.GetParameters().Last().ParameterType.GetGenericArguments().Length == 2);
var genericSelectFromLongToLong = method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] {typeof(long), typeof(long)});
```

Note that it would probably be better to check the generic arguments instead of the argument count for a match.